# Converting infix to postfix using c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, stack

I'm trying to convert infix to postfix. I don't think my code is wrong but apparently it is because it doesn't work. I don't know what to change to make my code work properly.

(It worked for a bit before and now it doesn't)

I followed this code from geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-set-2-infix-to-postfix/ but I changed some of it because the code from the website was also wrong.

Sorry if my explanation is a bit unclear. Here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int checks(char c)
{
    if (c=='^')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (c=='+' || c=='-')
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (c=='*' || c=='/')
    {
        return 3;
    } else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    stack <char> stack;
    string result, input;
    cout<<"Enter your equation: ";
    cin>> input;
    
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i+=1)
    {
        if (input[i]=='(')
        {
            stack.push(input[i]);
        } else if (isalnum(input[i]))
        {
            result+=input[i];
        } else if (input[i]==')')
        {
            while(!stack.empty() && stack.top() != '(') 
            { 
                char c = stack.top(); 
                stack.pop(); 
                result += c; 
            } 
            if(stack.top() == '(') 
            { 
                char c = stack.top(); 
                stack.pop(); 
            } 
        } else
        {
            if (checks(stack.top()) >= checks(input[i]))
            {
                result+=stack.top();
                stack.pop();
            } else
            {
                stack.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    while(!stack.empty())
    {
        if (stack.top()=='(' || stack.top()==')')
        {
            stack.pop();
        } else
        {
            result+=stack.top();
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"Result is: ";
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like stack is appropriate for this, it have single-direction associativity. You need a tree if you have to convert from classic notation to polish one. Actually , an example of such was in Stroustrup's book if I recall right, used to calculate expression, but it can be used for conversion

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie My prof haven't taught us how to use tree and he said to use stack. My highschool textbook also used stack to convert to RPN, but there's no code example at all.

Comment: Find the simplest test case that breaks. Step through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You may skip step to *actually* create a tree structure , but have to keep in mind that infix notation is representable by tree while Polish notation is representable by stack. In `(a+b)*(c+d)`  the `*` is topmost node, next level are two `+` and `a`, `b`,`c`,`d`. it's a symmetric tree because all operations commutative. But  `((a+b)*(c+d))/3`  is asymmetric, topmost node `/` is not commutative. Similar problem arise with `-`, because it's not commutative either.

E.g. possible option at each step can be (not a strict algorithm, but illustration how one should act, irt requires defense against malformed syntax)

1. Token is an "id".It's current level of tree node, scan further right
2. Token is a commutative operation. It's upper level of node. Next token would be a node of same level
3. Token is a non-commutative operation, / or -. It's upper level of node. Next token relates to node between current one and operation.
4. `*` and `/` have precedence above  `+` and `-`, so they are nodes of lower level. E.g. `a+b*c`, First our tree was  `+: [a,b]`, then it is `+:[a,*:[b,c]]`.
5. Token is `(`.  Scan string and  count all braces until you  find matching `)`. E.g.  each `(` increases counter, each `)` decreases. You found match if counter is 0. You have syntax error at hand if  you get positive or negative while reaching terminal character..
   Everything inside of () is a node of lower level. Scan it after finishing all upper levels.

To actually scan string, a state machine running in loop is required, the sign of finishing would be that there will be no tokens left to process. Can be recursive or not.

If you avoid creating tree, you have to go down and up along tokens in string itself, finding topmost node, push it to stack, then right and left nodes (in that order), push to stack, etc. When you pop stack, last-in first-out, operations would appear in proper order.

Paul Floyd is right to remind of that operator precedence can be used to sort order nodes or tokens, albeit doing it in `std::stack` is not possible because it got only push and pop operations and no reordering is possible, so you have to store that separately or scan and rescan string  to push appropriate elements in.

(Note, than when you use some RPN calculator like on of those TI ones the stack of operations acts as a LILO stack, while when convert from syntax tree to RPN, it's LIFO)

Answer (score 1):

Are your infix expressions using standard mathematical precedence? If so this will change things significantly compared to simple left to right evaluation.

You need to split your program into two phases. In the first phase you will parse the expression and build up the stack. In the second you will iterate over the stack and evaluate the result.

As I said, the parsing will be determined by the precedence. If you are using standard precedence then the usual approach (which you can read in Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language") is to use recursive descent. You would then have different precedences for parens, terms, factors, unary operators and literals. Use an enum for these, not magic numbers like 1, 2, 3.

Comment: I think some old edition of book literally had this task as example of state machine, but later editions went with OOP trees  and "algebraic" calculator. Or do I mix up his book and Paul Lucas's one?